# Arithmetic functions and Mobius Inversion.

Tags: number-theory

I have to show the following.

Let an arithmetic function $g$ defined by

$$(\sigma(n))^2=\sum_{d\mid n}g(d).$$

Prove that, for $p$ prime and $\alpha \in \mathbb{N}$, $g(p^{\alpha})=\dfrac{p^{\alpha} (p^{\alpha+1}+p^{\alpha}+2) }{p-1}$.

I have done the following. First I apply Mobius Inversion and get

$$g(n)=\sum_{d\mid n} \mu(\frac{n}{d})(\sigma(d))^2.$$

Since $\sigma$ and $\mu$ are multiplicative so is $g$. Then by multiplicative property I can evaluate $g$ at $p^\alpha$. Then

$$g(p^\alpha)=\sum_{d\mid p^\alpha} \mu(\frac{p^\alpha}{d})(\sigma(d))^2= \sum_{j=0}^{\alpha} \mu(p^{\alpha-j})(\sigma(p^j))^2.$$

Here I am stuck, any help I would appreciate. Or if I had made some mistake tell me.

Answer (score 0):

You are very close to the goal: you just have to exploit the fact that $\mu(p^{\alpha-j})$ is zero unless $j=\alpha$ or $j=\alpha-1$: compute $\sigma^2(p^j)$ in such cases and you will be done.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the general formula for $g(n)$ that you wrote down via
Mobius inversion.

As you say, by multiplicativity it suffices to compute $g(n)$ for $n$
a prime power.

Now
$$\sigma(p^a)^2-\sigma(p^{a-1})^2
=\sum_{j=0}^a g(p^j)-\sum_{j=0}^{a-1} g(p^j)
=g(p^a).$$
So all you have to do is calculate $\sigma(p^a)^2-\sigma(p^{a-1})^2$.